# Integration of $e^{-it\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2 + m^2}}$ for QM amplitude

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration, propagator

My question might be more about maths than physics, but it originated in a Physics context.

Take $\hbar$ = $c$ = 1.

I was looking at the amplitude for a free particle to propagate from an initial position $\mathbf{r_0}$ to a final position $\mathbf{r}$, call it $A(t)$: $$ A(t) = \langle \mathbf{r}|e^{-i\hat{H}t}|\mathbf{r_0}\rangle, $$
with $\hat{H} = \sqrt{\mathbf{\hat{p}}^2 + m^2}$, so $$ A(t) = \frac{1}{{2\pi}^3} \int d^3p \cdot e^{-it\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2 + m^2}} \cdot e^{i\mathbf{p}(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0})}.$$

How do you integrate this?

And more generally, how do you integrate a >1 function where you **cannot** separate all the the variables? I.e. in this case the integration is over $p_x$, $p_y$ and $p_z$ but the $\mathbf{p}^2$ is under the square root so we can't just separate each component and integrate it...

By the way this integral is feasible, the answer apparently is as follows (I just have no idea how to get to it!): $$ A(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2 |\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}|} \int dp\cdot p\cdot \sin(p|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r_0}|)e^{-it\sqrt{p^2 + m^2}}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First go to spherical coordinates:
$$
A(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi^3}\int_0^{\infty}\text{d} p\int_0^{2\pi}\text{d} \phi \int_0^{\pi}\text{d}\theta\text{ } p^2 \sin\theta e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}} e^{ip\cos\theta|r-r_0|},
$$
and perform the trivial integral over $\phi$. Subsequently substitute $y=\cos\theta$ such that $\text{d}y=\sin\theta\text{d}\theta$ and integrate over $y$:
\begin{align}
A(t) &= \frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\infty}\text{d}p\text{ }p^2e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}\int_{-1}^1\text{d} y e^{ipy|r-r_0|} \nonumber \\
&=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_0^{\infty}\text{d}p\text{ }p^2e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}} \Big(\frac{1}{ip|r-r_0|} \Big)\Big(e^{ip|r-r_0|}-e^{-ip|r-r_0|}\Big) \nonumber \\
&=\frac{2}{\pi^2|r-r_0|}\int_0^{\infty}\text{d} p \text{ } p e^{-it\sqrt{p^2+m^2}}\sin(p|r-r_0|)
\end{align}

EDIT: I am pretty sure my factor of two in the numerator is correct. Maybe your initial function $A(t)$ is defined with the conventional $1/(2\pi)^3$, instead of $1/(2\pi^3)$?

Comment: Thanks very much.
Yes, your factor is correct, I forgot to put brackets